# How export class diagrams/UML in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: uml, visual-studio-2013, class-diagram

Trying to export my designs to PDF/PNG/GIF or anything really but I have no idea how and internet wasn't very helpful. Don't really understand why I can't just right click an export :(
Any help is greatly appreciated cheers, I am using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, all I had to do was Ctrl+A (select all my classes), Ctrl+C and go into a Word document and Ctrl+V. It turned out quite good.

This trick is not easily seen but below statement kinda hints

> *If you want to export a document to an image manually, you can copy and paste the shapes from a diagram into other programs such as Word.*

in

[How to: Export UML Diagrams to Image Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469815.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you *can* right-click and export.  In Visual Studio, open the class diagram (.cd file).  Right-click anywhere in the blank canvas area (i.e. not on a shape), and select Export Diagram as Image:

[image]

That will give you a dialog that allows you to choose destination, format, etc.

Comment: This works on the "class diagram" .cd files in C# project, but not "UML class diagrams" which are .classdiagram files in a UML project.  Thanks, Microsoft!

Comment: Ah - missed that - I do see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an MSDN article that gives code for creating a Visual Studio shortcut to export your selected UML to an image file

[How to: Export UML Diagrams to Image Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469815.aspx)

Requires you to do a bit of work but pretty sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As [WiSeeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944091/wiseeker) mentioned above

> "Actually, all I had to do was Ctrl+A (select all my classes), Ctrl+C and go into a Word document and Ctrl+V. It turned out quite good."

Occasionally this does not work using **Word**... The [.pdf](/questions/tagged/.pdf) does not render the image properly.

Alternatively you can use the same method mentioned by [WiSeeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944091/wiseeker), but instead of converting the [.docx](/questions/tagged/.docx) to a [.pdf](/questions/tagged/.pdf) using **Word**.

I pasted the **UML** diagram into **Visio**, then converted to [.pdf](/questions/tagged/.pdf) using **Visio**.